# Cannot seem to get Eclipse IDE to find the geckodriver on my Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

The error being returned is: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /usr/local/bin/geckodriver⁩"

The driver is there as you can see:
➜ bin pwd
/usr/local/bin
➜ bin ls geck*
geckodriver

I've searched the many other answers to this same question on the forum but nothing I've tried has a made a difference. I initially installed the geckodriver manually, but when I couldn't get it to work I deleted the file and installed it via brew install, but it didn't make a difference.

```
package automationFramework;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class WebTestMainPage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/usr/local/bin/geckodriver⁩");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.store.demoqa.com");
```

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0)
Build id: 20181214-0600
OS: Mac OS X, v.10.14.2, x86_64 / cocoa
Java version: 11.0.1

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the geckodriver executable first and then you would be able to execute the script.
To make it executable you need to go the folder where its located, in your case its /usr/local/bin and then make it executable using chmod +x command.
Try following steps:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
chmod +x geckodriver
```

Now you would be able to execute your script.

Comment: Nah. Thanks for the suggestion but I am a UX user... it is an executable in ref to permissions. Thanks again.